# Quickest way to NULL or wipe a column

Tags: sql-server

I have a unique situation, where I need to anonymize a column quickly. By that I mean any way to remove the data, whether it is NULL'ing, blanking or something else. There can be up to 20 million records to update and there are no indexes on the column I am updating.

I have tried a couple of things, for instance:

```
Update TABLE Set COLUMN = NULL
```

This clearly is the worst performing query. I have modified it to exclude any current NULLs or blanks from that set, but it is still very slow.

I have tried to drop and re-create the column, which so far is instant. But unfortunately because of business **reasons**, the column order is important, so this ruins that. (For the purpose of the question assume reordering columns is impossible).

Recently I tried to change the column type to `char(1)`, then back to `text` - which had better performance. However, after seeing it run lightning fast with a drop and re-create column, I am curious if there is a way to do this with keeping the column order intact. Clearly SQL Server is capable of producing ~20 million records as NULLs instantly - there must be a clever way around this?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

First let's do a quick review of how SQL Server generates the default ordering of columns when you do a `SELECT *` query. There are probably a few edge cases but I believe that columns are returned in the order that they are created. If a column is dropped the ordinal ID associated with that column is not used and cannot be used by a new column.

Consider this sample table:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.SEE_COLUMN_ORDER (
COL1 INT,
COL2 INT,
COL3 INT,
COL4 INT
);
```

We can see the column_id using this query against [sys.columns](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-catalog-views/sys-columns-transact-sql):

```
SELECT name, column_id
FROM sys.columns
WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID('SEE_COLUMN_ORDER');
```

Initial results:

```
╔══════╦═══════════╗
║ name ║ column_id ║
╠══════╬═══════════╣
║ COL1 ║         1 ║
║ COL2 ║         2 ║
║ COL3 ║         3 ║
║ COL4 ║         4 ║
╚══════╩═══════════╝
```

Now drop a column:

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.SEE_COLUMN_ORDER DROP COLUMN COL3;
```

New results:

```
╔══════╦═══════════╗
║ name ║ column_id ║
╠══════╬═══════════╣
║ COL1 ║         1 ║
║ COL2 ║         2 ║
║ COL4 ║         4 ║
╚══════╩═══════════╝
```

Now add a column:

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.SEE_COLUMN_ORDER ADD COL3 INT;
```

New results:

```
╔══════╦═══════════╗
║ name ║ column_id ║
╠══════╬═══════════╣
║ COL1 ║         1 ║
║ COL2 ║         2 ║
║ COL4 ║         4 ║
║ COL3 ║         5 ║
╚══════╩═══════════╝
```

There is no column with a `column_id` of 3. As far as I can tell there is no known or supported way of making `COL3` have a `column_id` of 3. If you wanted that column to be displayed third in a `SELECT *` query you could define a view against the table with the name and a different schema or you could drop and recreate the entire table with the column order that you want.

Recreating an entire table sounds like a slow operation but sometimes it can be quicker than updating all of the rows for a single column. It'll depend on your system, your table structure, and the data in your table. One scenario in which the drop and create might be faster is if your transaction log writes are the bottleneck. With a recovery model of simple you can create the new table with minimal logging which will write very little data to the transaction log compared to the `UPDATE`. Another scenario in which the drop and recreate can be faster is if the `UPDATE` will lead to a lot of page splits. It's possible to construct a table and an `UPDATE` which splits every data page into two (an `UPDATE` to a column value making it `NULL` won't do this as far as I know). As a general rule of thumb, the same amount of data is saved to the log regardless of the recovery model unless the operation can be minimally logged. `UPDATE` is never minimally logged so switching to simple won't reduce the transaction log requirements for that operation.

To cover the part of the question that deals with performance, one important thing to note is that adding and dropping a column to an existing table are optimized operations that have a fixed cost that doesn't scale with the amount of data in the table. To see this in action I'm going to look at how much data is logged in the transaction log for the operations (dropping and adding columns can be rolled back in a transaction). I'm testing against SQL Server 2016.

Here is the sample data:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS dbo.X_COLUMN_WIPE_2;
CREATE TABLE dbo.X_COLUMN_WIPE_2 (
    ID INT NOT NULL IDENTITY (1, 1),
    COL_TO_WIPE VARCHAR(1) NULL,
    FILLER VARCHAR(100) NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (ID)
);

-- 2536 rows
INSERT INTO dbo.X_COLUMN_WIPE_2 WITH (TABLOCK)
SELECT 'A', REPLICATE('Z', 100)
FROM master..spt_values t1;
```

Per [sys.dm_tran_database_transactions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-dynamic-management-views/sys-dm-tran-database-transactions-transact-sql), the `UPDATE` writes 324752 log bytes to the transaction log:

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION

UPDATE dbo.X_COLUMN_WIPE_2 SET COL_TO_WIPE = NULL; 

ROLLBACK;
```

Dropping and adding a column writes just 1992 log bytes to the log:

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION

ALTER TABLE dbo.X_COLUMN_WIPE_2 DROP COLUMN COL_TO_WIPE;

ALTER TABLE dbo.X_COLUMN_WIPE_2 ADD NEW_COLUMN VARCHAR(1) NULL;

ROLLBACK;
```

Now to test with more data:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS dbo.X_COLUMN_WIPE_3;

CREATE TABLE dbo.X_COLUMN_WIPE_3 (
    ID INT NOT NULL IDENTITY (1, 1),
    COL_TO_WIPE VARCHAR(1) NULL,
    FILLER VARCHAR(100) NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (ID)
);

-- 6431296 rows
INSERT INTO dbo.X_COLUMN_WIPE_3 WITH (TABLOCK)
SELECT 'A', REPLICATE('Z', 100)
FROM master..spt_values t1
CROSS JOIN master..spt_values t2;
```

The same `UPDATE` now writes 721979808 bytes to the transaction log but dropping and creating a column still writes just 1992 bytes.

It's possible to dig into the internals of why this happens using the [undocumented DBCC PAGE](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1578/using-dbcc-page-to-examine-sql-server-table-and-index-data/). Here's an example from when I ran the code on my system (copying and pasting the code won't work because the page numbers will be different):

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS dbo.X_COLUMN_WIPE_4;
CREATE TABLE dbo.X_COLUMN_WIPE_4 (
    ID INT NOT NULL IDENTITY (1, 1),
    COL_TO_WIPE VARCHAR(1) NULL,
    FILLER VARCHAR(100) NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (ID)
);

INSERT INTO dbo.X_COLUMN_WIPE_4 WITH (TABLOCK)
SELECT 'A', REPLICATE('Z', 100)
FROM master..spt_values t1;

-- first first data page
DBCC IND('SE_DB',X_COLUMN_WIPE_4,-1)

-- view first data page
DBCC TRACEON(3604)
DBCC PAGE('SE_DB',1,1192232,3);

BEGIN TRANSACTION

UPDATE dbo.X_COLUMN_WIPE_4 SET COL_TO_WIPE = NULL; 

DBCC PAGE('SE_DB',1,1192232,3);

ROLLBACK;
```

As Paul White would say I'm quite the amateur when it comes to this stuff, but I'll give my interpretation anyway. Here's a diff of what's in the page for the first record in the table before and after the update:

[image: page after update]

I underlined what I suspect are the important pages in red. Note that many of the physical lengths have changed and that the value "A" for `COL_TO_WIPE` is no longer present in the row data. It looks like the `UPDATE` changed much of the data stored in the page.

Here's a diff between the original table and after the `COL_TO_WIPE` column is dropped:

[image: after drop]

The number of differences is much smaller than before. None of the row data is changed. I believe that there is just a metadata operation performed on the table outside of the table pages, so all of the changes displayed by `DBCC PAGE` here are logical as opposed to physical.

Here's a diff between the original table and after the column is dropped and a new column is added:

[image: add column]

As before there don't really appear to be any physical differences. The actual data looks to be the exact same. There are just column definitions with a physical length of 0.

Since the problem here appears to be related to how the date is stored row by row in pages, perhaps the results would be different for tables created as clustered columnstore indexes which are stored in column format. After all, it is reasonable to think that updating a column value should only affect the one column instead of all of the data in the table. Unfortunately for this case, the current implementation of `UPDATE` against CCIs is a logical delete and insert. So if you update all of the rows for a column to be `NULL`, SQL Server will mark all of the existing rows in the table as logically deleted and will create new rowgroups for all of the rows.

In summary, other than recreating the whole table you've already mentioned all of the "clever" ways in the question that I know of for working around your problem. It's very unlikely that there is an "instant" way to update a column to be `NULL` in the middle of the table without breaking the previous column order in the table.